# udp streaming from Gstreaming to VLC not worked

Tags: xamarin, gstreamer, vlc, pi, sdp

I just make Xamarin.Android APP for live streaming using PI4 Cam.

I used GStreamer in Sender(Pi4) and VLC in Receiver(Windosw Visual Studio).

tried this below

Sender - GStreamer in Raspberry :

```
raspivid -t 0 -w 800 -h 600 -fps 30-hf -vf -b 50000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=192.168.43.201 port=5000
```

Receiver - VLC SDP file :

```
c=IN IP4 10.5.110.117
t=0 0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

When I received it with Gstreamer on Windows, it's very well and no latency so I wanna take this option.
But I could only get a still shot on VLC(stopped at a paused time 0:00)

Is that SDP file wrong?

Plz give me some advice on what I should try. :)

Comment: The IP Address was wrong in the question, but the IP was correct. I wrote it wrong.